# Android Tool for images design

Tags: android

Actually i just want to have a tool which can help me creating different resolution images , cropping and slicing images for android, a easy to use and quality work tool. please let me know if you have any tool in your knowledge.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I just wrote a tool that helps here. It lets you easily view all resolutions, and scale/copy from one to the other. http://hobbyistsoftware.com/AndroidImageViewer

Answer (score 2):

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/
Just upload your image and it will do the rest :)